# Positioning <img> element

Tags: html, css

I have tried multiple things but not position `<img>` at desired position. It is always stuck between two spans. Tried to img out of the child `div` and add it to the parent div. But no luck. I want to position it below my spans and with `padding-top:20px;`.This image is a 200x38px image. Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="col1-step2">
          <div class="heading-step2">
            <span class="heading-step2">Hello signed User.</span>
            <span class="heading-step2 textblue">How are you doing.</span>
            <img class="user-bar" src="<?php echo site_url('img/bar.png'); ?>">
          </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.col1-step2 {
  float: left;
  width: 40%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);

}
div.heading-step2 {
  top: 6%;
  position: relative;
}

.heading-step2 {
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #f7f7f7;
}
.heading-step2 .textblue {
  color: #55c7fa;
  font-weight: bold; 
  display: block;
}
img.user-bar {
  position: absolute;
  padding-top: 25%;
}
```

Comment: What is the desired positioning?

Comment: where you want to position it

Comment: Edited my question. I want it below the spans with some 20px padding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a mix of relative and absolute positioning. By removing the absolute positioning on the image and restructuring the HTML you can get different element ordering:

http://jsfiddle.net/HhbQB/1/

```
<div class="col1-step2">
    <div class="heading-step2">
        <span class="heading-step2">Hello signed User.</span>
        <img class="user-bar" src="http://placehold.it/200x100" />
        <span class="heading-step2 textblue">How are you doing.</span>    
    </div>
</div>
```

Updated fiddle in response to your comment: http://jsfiddle.net/HhbQB/2/

Comment: After removing postition:relative from .user-bar, image is in next line. But padding-top:25% doesn't work.

Comment: It does for me in both of the fiddles I posted.

Comment: Could it be because parent div is nested inside other divs?

Comment: Now image is just below the second span. I want to have some margin between these two elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can give relative or absolute position to your divs, if you want help then try giving location where you want the div to be.